# Add plugin directory

Tags: plugin-system

When I install plugins, I like to keep them organised in folders. For example, I have downloaded plugins that turn vim into a programming IDE. This file contains 16 folders and files which are installed in the `~/.vim` directory. Is there a way I can have all of these files and folders stored in `~/.vim/ide_support`?

Comment: Have you ever tried https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim or https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen?

Comment: No I haven't. Only started using vim 1-2 days ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unpack the plugin into `~/.vim/ide_support` then add the following to your `.vimrc`.

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/ide_support
```

Vim will now look in `~/.vim/ide_support` for plugins.

This is one of the things that a plugin manager such as [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) does for you automatically.